# Python Loop until condition is met

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to write a program for an assignment and for one section, I need to create division questions. I need it so that when the random numbers are picked, the first number will always be larger than the second number. the function that I have created does most of the work but I cant seem to figure out how to get it to loop until the condition is met. In the code, I have tried using a while loop but when I run it, I still get the first number as being a lower number.

Does anyone have any recommendations as to how I could do this?

```
import random
import time

score = 0
Addition = range(1, 20)
Multiplication = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
Division = ['1', '2', '4', '6', '8', '10']

def additionfunc():
 for x in range (0, 4):
  a = random.choice(Addition)
  b = random.choice(Addition)

  c = float(a) + float(b)
  print("What is", a," plus", b)
  answer = int(input("Please enter your answer: "))

  if answer == c:
     print("Correct")
     print("Plus 10 points")
     global score
     score = score + 10
     print()
     time.sleep(1)
  else:
     print("Incorrect")
     print("No points added")
     print()
     time.sleep(1)
     print("Well done, your score was", score)
     print()
mainmenu()

def multiplicationfunc():
 for x in range (0, 4):
  a = random.choice(Multiplication)
  b = random.choice(Multiplication)
  c = float(a) * float(b)

  print("What is", a," multiplied by", b)
  answer = int(input("Please enter your answer: "))

 if answer == c:
  print("Correct")
  print("Plus 10 points")
  global score
  score = score + 10
  print()
  time.sleep(1)
 else:
  print("Incorrect")
  print("No points added")
  print()
  time.sleep(1)
  print("Well done, your score was", score)
  print()
mainmenu()

def divisionfunc():
 for x in range (0,4):
  a = random.choice(Division)
  b = random.choice(Division)
  c = float(a) / float(b)

  print("What is", a, "divided by", b)
  answer = float(input("Please enter your answer: "))

  if answer == c:
   print("Correct")
   print("Plus 10 points")
   global score
   score = score +10
   print()
   time.sleep(1)
 else:
   print("Incorrect")
   print("No points added")
   print()
   time.sleep(1)
   print("Well done, your score was", score)
   print()
mainmenu()

def mainmenu():
 print("Welcome to the Numeracy Game")
 print("1. Addition")
 print("2. Multiplication")
 print("3. Division")
 print("Score =", score)
 time.sleep(2)

 Genre = int(input("Enter the value for the mode:"))
 print()

if Genre == 1:
 additionfunc()
elif Genre == 2:
 multiplicationfunc()
elif Genre == 3:
 divisionfunc()

mainmenu();
```

Comment: A can't be always bigger in your example if they get randomly picked from the same sequence. Also please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I changed the questions so all of the code is in

Comment: The indentation is probably not right on here since I had to change it all when I copied it in

Comment: To correctly show code in SO paste the code block in, select it and click the `{}` button to convert to a code block (indents it)

Comment: Please note the _Minimal_ part of "Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable". Cut anything out of your code that isn't necessary, leaving just enough for someone else to reproduce your issue.

Comment: _"I have tried using a while loop but when I run it, I still get [wrong result]"_  **show only the code relevant to your attempt.** Tell us what you think it should do, what it is actually doing and why what it is actually doing doesn't make sense to you.  Showing your whole program that doesn't even try to solve the issue you are asking about isn't going to get you (helpful) answers.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you need:

```
division= ['1', '2', '4', '6', '8', '10'] #[1,2,4,6,8,10]
# you could also use random.randint(start, stop)
#if you only want even ints you can use random.randint(0,10,2)
a = random.choice(division) # random.ranint(0,10)
b = random.choice(division) # random.randint(0,10)
if b == 10:
    #prevents b from being the biggest number which would result in an endless loop
    b = random.choice(division)
while a < b or a==b: # if a is smaller or same as b change a
    a = random.choice(division)
else:
    # it would be easier to use ints instead string and only convert
    # them to string in your print statemnt
    c = float(a)/float(b)
```

Comment: I tried using it but it seems that I get an invalid syntax error on the c = float(a)/float(b)

Comment: Just checked again and it works for me. Mabye you misstyped sth?

Comment: Seems I have found a fix for the issue, I appreciate the help. The issue was that the while loop that I orginally made was right but I didnt change my list from strings into integers.